# What's the best web entrepeneur's conference to go on

Tags: web-development, marketing

Our dream as business partners was always to go to a conference overseas.

Now that we can finally afford to, we have no clue of which one to go to.

Which conference would you guys suggest from a web entrepeneur's point of view, if there were just one to go to?

Perhaps something that included a bit of marketing, new thinking, innovation, inspiration.

We were very keen on Google IO previously, but were concerned that it would be very Google product focused.

Huge thanks!

Comment: Made this community wiki since there is no right answer

Comment: Can you define "overseas" please.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Eric Ries conference on Lean Startups if you want web entrepreneurs point of views on new thinking :-)

http://lanyrd.com/profile/ericries/2012/

His blog

http://www.startuplessonslearned.com/

Generally speaking, if you want to contribute to the world at the same time, try TED conferences :-)